# ComponentDidMount doesn' detect Metamask change account

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, javascript, addresses

I'm quite new to Web3 and Metamask and would like to ask how should I change the basic componenDidMount of the React truffle box so that it can detect and change accounts when I'm switching an account on Metamask.

Here is the code:

```
Class App extends Component {
    state = {
    web3: null,
    contract: undefined,
    account: null
    }
componentDidMount = async () => {
  try {
  // Get network provider and web3 instances.
  const web3 = await getWeb3();

  // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  // Get the contract instance.
  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
  const deployedNetwork = SupChain.networks[networkId];
  const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(SupChain.abi, deployedNetwork && 
  deployedNetwork.address);
  // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state
  this.setState({ contract: instance, web3: web3, account: accounts[0] });
} catch (error) {
  // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
     alert(`Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
  );
  console.error(error);
}
   };
}
```

I thanks in advance anybody that will take the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metamask fires events when the user changes account, logs out, changes the network.
Start reading the [official documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#events) to see how to implement the event listeners.